# Android Oreo: URI from ACTION_GET_CONTENT is not granted with FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION when wrapped with Intent.createChooser

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am getting the below exception when using Intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT wrapped with Intent.createChooser. I don't get this exception when I don't wrap the Intent with  Intent.createChooser..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/523 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.mycompany.app/com.mycompany.app.activity.MessageCompose}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{..} (pid=20538, uid=10127) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

Code that has problem:-

```java
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
i.setType(type);
i = Intent.createChooser(i, "Select a file");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_PICK_ATTACHMENT);
```

The code works when I remove the line

```java
i = Intent.createChooser(i, "Select a file");
```

When I checked onActivityResult

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
...
uri = data.getData();

int permissionGrant = getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfUriPermission(uri,  Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
// Returns PERMISSION_GRANTED without createChooser 
// Returns PERMISSION_DENIED with createChooser
```

Manifest file:-

```xml
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mycompany.app.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/providers_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

How to fix this problem, when using the chooser.

Comment: Have a look at this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554617/uri-location-to-save-a-photo/56555126#56555126

Comment: I don't have the handle to the file URI, before launching the Intent. The purpose to launch the Intent is let users select a file. I get hold of the provider uri at onActivityResult only